# What if the value cannot be accurate to one decimal place?

Tags: publications, formatting

I have read a lot of papers, and the tables they draw are accurate to one decimal place. But my data looks like this: `0.003%` `12.736%` `19.255` and so on. If it is accurate to one decimal place, `0.003%` is **zero**. There are three more data in my table: `5.265*10^8`  `6.840∗10^4`  `2.213∗10^3` and their sum is `5.266∗10^8`, but if I am accurate to one decimal place, it becomes `5.26∗10^8` `6.84∗10^4` `2.21∗10^3`, their sum is `5.26∗10^8`. The sum equals the first addend.

How precise should I be?

Comment: Use significant figures not decimal places.

Comment: Also, read up on the general topic of uncertainty analysis. Stopping at sig figures is sometimes sufficient, often not.

Comment: This question is answered thoroughly in books on uncertainty analysis as well as in textbooks for first year courses in chemistry or physics.. It belongs in Engineering, Chemistry, or Physics stacks. If you move it to one of those sites, include information on the specific part of the background reading that you have done in the reference books where you are not able to master the concepts in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking about data in terms of decimal places is misleading.  You should really be thinking about data in terms of the precision with which you know the values, also sometimes referred to as [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

How precisely do you actually know those values? It is 12.736% because you actually have enough data to say that it is accurate to one part in 100,000, or is it because of something like Excel defaulting to three decimal places?

You need to figure out the amount of error in your measurements, and once you know that, then the answer to your questions will be clear.

Comment: +1 Setting up a measurement instrument such that you can distinguish between 12.736% and 12.737% is in most cases an *extreme* investement in time, efort and resources. So if you have such an extremely accurate measurement, then you know about it. In other words, if this isn't screamed at you every time you approach the data, then you can be pretty certain that it is not that accurate, and 12.736% in reality just means 13%.

Comment: @MaartenBuis  "You can be pretty certain" is not a scientific principle. You need to know the specifics of the source of the data. Accuracy varies widely. I have examples of data with 7 sig digits. I have a case where the magnitude has uncertainty. I have a case where the sign of the value is uncertain.